# Saving post from tweepy to django model in a good way

Tags: django, twitter, django-models, tweepy

I was wondering if any could point me in the right direction.
I'm trying to fetch twitter data and save it to a DB (with Django ORM / models).

My first approach was to create a model with all relevant information of a tweet (Status) like this:

```
class Tweet(models.Model):
    """
    A tweet (Status) with all the respective metadata
    """
     id = models.BigIntegerField()
     lang = models.CharField(max_length=10)
     retweet_count = models.PositiveIntegerField()
     text = models.CharField(max_lenght=150)
     source = ....
     ....
```

And then fetching like:

```
#Almost pseudocode
from monitoring.models import Tweet
status = api.get_status('xxxx') # A simple tweet status with tweepy
newtweet = Tweet(id=status.id, screen_name = status.screen_name, followers_count = status.followers_count)
newtweet.save()
```

I guess I could do better and easy with tweepy [models factory](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/tweepy/models.py#L418) but I can't go in the right direction by my own...any suggest? Any example/link/article would be great.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am trying to solve the exact same problem

Answer (score 0):

we used pickle and saved the twitter data in a variable(hard disk) if that helps you. Just use pickle in your model like this:

```
import pickle
filename = 'finalized_model.sav'
pickle.dump(LR_model, open(filename, 'wb'))
pickl={'vectorizer':tf_vector,'model':LR_model,'clean':clean()}
pickle.dump(pickl,open('models'+".p","wb"))
```

and then put this in your django apps.py:

```
path = os.path.join(settings.MODELS, 'models.p')
    with open(path, 'rb') as pickled:
        data = pickle.load(pickled)
    model = data['model']
    vectorizer = data['vectorizer']
```

given that you have declared your model in setting.py. then fetch twitter data use it in views.py